# How do I draw a circle in a Qt QML TableView cell?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I have a simple sample project [here](https://github.com/jh3010-qt-questions/TableView) which demonstrate the problem.

I've included below what I believe is the relevant source, but the remainder is available in the project link above or I can edit and include more if useful.

Based on some research, it appears that I need to use the `Qt::DecorationRole` in my data function and return an image when the column is 1. However, that part of the code is never executed. I am missing some important and obvious about how the role concept works with Qt QML `TableView`'s.

What do I need to change so I can draw a circle in Column 1 (average age)? I'd like this circle to be red if the `age < 13`, yellow if `< 35`, and green otherwise.

`main.qml`

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
import Qt.labs.qmlmodels 1.0

import Backend 1.0

ApplicationWindow
{
  id:      root
  visible: true

  width:  768
  height: 450

  minimumWidth:  768
  minimumHeight: 450

  property string backendReference: Backend.objectName

  TableView
  {
    id: tableView

    columnWidthProvider: function( column )
    {
      return 100;
    }

    rowHeightProvider: function( column )
    {
      return 23;
    }

    anchors.fill: parent
    topMargin:    columnsHeader.implicitHeight

    model: Backend.modelResults.list

    ScrollBar.horizontal: ScrollBar {}
    ScrollBar.vertical:   ScrollBar {}

    clip: true

    delegate: DelegateChooser {
//      role: "type"

      DelegateChoice {
        roleValue: "decoration"

        Rectangle
        {
          color: 'red'

          anchors.fill: parent
        }
      }

      DelegateChoice {
//        roleValue: "display"

        Rectangle
        {
          Text
          {
            text: display
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.margins: 10
            color: 'black'
            font.pixelSize: 15
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
          }
        }
      }

    }

//        Rectangle
//    {
//      Text
//      {
//        text: display
//        anchors.fill: parent
//        anchors.margins: 10
//        color: 'black'
//        font.pixelSize: 15
//        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
//      }
//    }

    Rectangle // mask the headers
    {
      z: 3

      color: "#222222"

      y: tableView.contentY
      x: tableView.contentX

      width:  tableView.leftMargin
      height: tableView.topMargin
    }

    Row
    {
      id: columnsHeader
      y:  tableView.contentY

      z: 2

      Repeater
      {
        model: tableView.columns > 0 ? tableView.columns : 1

        Label
        {
          width:  tableView.columnWidthProvider(modelData)
          height: 35

          text: Backend.modelResults.list.headerData( modelData, Qt.Horizontal )

          font.pixelSize:    15
          padding:           10
          verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter

          background: Rectangle
          {
            color: "#eeeeee"
          }
        }
      }
    }

    ScrollIndicator.horizontal: ScrollIndicator { }
    ScrollIndicator.vertical: ScrollIndicator { }
  }
}
```

`modeldata.cpp`

```
#include "modeldata.h"

//
// ModelList
//
ModelList::
ModelList( QObject* parent )
    : QAbstractTableModel (parent )
{
//  mRoleNames = QAbstractTableModel::roleNames();
//  mRoleNames.insert( 1, QByteArray( "type" ) );

}



int
ModelList::
rowCount(const QModelIndex &) const
{
   int size = mList.size();

   return size;
}



int
ModelList::
columnCount( const QModelIndex & ) const
{
   return 2;
}




QVariant
ModelList::
data( const QModelIndex& index, int role ) const
{
    const ModelItem modelItem = mList.at( index.row() );

    QVariant result = QVariant();

    if ( role == Qt::DisplayRole )
    {
        if ( index.column() == 0 )
        {
          result = QVariant( QString( modelItem.population ) );
        }
        else
        {
          result = QVariant( QString::number( modelItem.averageAge ) );
        }
    }

    if ( role == Qt::DecorationRole )
    {
        qDebug() << "decorate 1";
    }

    return result;
}



QVariant
ModelList::
headerData( int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role ) const
{
    if ( section == 0 )
        return QVariant( QString( "Population" ) );
    else
        return QVariant( QString( "Average Age" ) );
}



int
ModelList::
size() const
{
    return mList.size();
}



const QList<ModelItem>&
ModelList::
list() const
{
    return mList;
}



void
ModelList::
removeAt( int index )
{
    if ( index < 0 || index >= mList.size() )
        return;

    beginRemoveRows( QModelIndex(), index, index );
    mList.removeAt( index );
    endRemoveRows();

    emit sizeChanged();
}



void
ModelList::
add( const QString& population, const int averageAge )
{
    ModelItem item;

    item.population = population;
    item.averageAge = averageAge;

    add( item );
}

QHash<int, QByteArray>
ModelList::
roleNames() const
{
  return {
    { Qt::DisplayRole, "display" },
    { Qt::DecorationRole, "decorations" }
  };

//  return this->mRoleNames;
}



void
ModelList::
add(const ModelItem& item)
{
    const int index = mList.size();

    beginInsertRows( QModelIndex(), index, index );
    mList.append( item );
    endInsertRows();

    emit sizeChanged();
}



void
ModelList::
reset()
{
    if ( mList.isEmpty() )
        return;

    beginRemoveRows( QModelIndex(), 0, mList.size() - 1 );
    mList.clear();
    endRemoveRows();

    emit sizeChanged();
}



//
// ModelResults
//
ModelResults::ModelResults(QObject* parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{
    mList = new ModelList( this );

    qRegisterMetaType<ModelItem>("ModelItem");
}

ModelList* ModelResults::list() const
{
    return mList;
}

void ModelResults::reset()
{
    mList->reset();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to get the correct circle drawn in the averageAge field.

My ModelItem looks like:

```
struct ModelItem
{
    Q_GADGET

    Q_PROPERTY( QString population MEMBER population )
    Q_PROPERTY( int averageAge MEMBER averageAge )
    Q_PROPERTY( bool selected MEMBER selected )

public:

    enum class Role {
      Selection = Qt::UserRole,
      ColumnType,
      ColorValue
    };
    Q_ENUM(Role)

    QString population;
    int     averageAge;
    bool    selected    { false };

    bool operator!=( const ModelItem& other )
    {
        return other.population != this->population
            || other.averageAge != this->averageAge;
    }

};
```

The key point here is the definition of the ColumnType and ColorValue Role.

I needed a roleNames function for my custom role

```
QHash<int, QByteArray>
ModelList::
roleNames() const
{
  return {
    { Qt::DisplayRole, "display" },
    { int( ModelItem::Role::Selection ), "selected" },
    { int( ModelItem::Role::ColumnType ), "type" },
    { int( ModelItem::Role::ColorValue ), "colorValue" }
  };
}
```

The custom roles needed to be supplied by roleNames and have the strings "type" and "colorValue" specified.

My data function looks like:

```
QVariant
ModelList::
data( const QModelIndex& index, int role ) const
{
    const ModelItem modelItem = mList.at( index.row() );

    QVariant result = QVariant();

    if ( role == Qt::DisplayRole )
    {
        if ( index.column() == 0 )
        {
          result = QVariant( QString( modelItem.population ) );
        }
        else
        {
          result = QVariant( QString::number( modelItem.averageAge ) );
        }
    }

    if ( role == int( ModelItem::Role::Selection ) )
    {
        result = QVariant( QString( modelItem.selected ? "#eeeeee" : "white" ) );
    }

    if ( role == int( ModelItem::Role::ColumnType ) )
    {
      if ( index.column() == 0 )
        result = QVariant( QString( "stringValue" ) );
      else
        result = QVariant( QString( "colorValue" ) );
    }

    if ( role == int( ModelItem::Role::ColorValue ) )
    {
      QString color;

      if ( modelItem.averageAge < 13 )
        color = "red";
      else if ( modelItem.averageAge < 35 )
        color = "yellow";
      else
        color = "green";

      result = QVariant( color );
    }

    qDebug() << role << " " << result;

    return result;
}
```

A key point here is that when the role ColumnType is used, I return whether or not the column is a stringValue or a colorValue.

Additionally, when the role ColorValue is used, I look at the averageAge of the modelItem and return a string containing the color to be used.

The final piece is to have the QML use the custom roles.

```
delegate: DelegateChooser
{
  role: "type"

  DelegateChoice
  {
    roleValue: "colorValue"

    delegate: Rectangle
    {
      color: selected

      Rectangle
      {
        color: colorValue

        width: parent.height
        height: parent.height

        radius: width * 0.5;

        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter;
      }

      MouseArea
      {
        anchors.fill: parent

        onClicked:
        {
          var idx = Backend.modelResults.list.index( row, column )

          console.log( "Clicked cell: ", idx.row, " ", Backend.modelResults.list.data( idx ) )

          Backend.modelResults.list.select( idx.row );
        }
      }
    }
  }

  DelegateChoice
  {
    delegate: Rectangle
    {
      color: selected

      Text
      {
        text: display
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 10
        color: 'black'
        font.pixelSize: 15
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
      }

      MouseArea
      {
        anchors.fill: parent

        onClicked:
        {
          var idx = Backend.modelResults.list.index( row, column )

          console.log( "Clicked cell: ", idx.row, " ", Backend.modelResults.list.data( idx ) )

          Backend.modelResults.list.select( idx.row );
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

First, for the DelegateChooser, the role is specified by our custom "type" role. The system knows to call our data function with this role. When the data function returns "colorValue", the first DelegateChoice is selected based because the roleValue is "colorValue". The second DelegateChoice does not have a roleValue because it appears there needs to be a default DelegateChoice and "stringValue" is the default.

Second, the "colorValue" delegate choice has defined `color: colorValue`. This causes the system to again call the data function with the ColorValue role and it then returns the correct color for the cell.

The example project has been updated.

Suggested improvement to this solution are welcome.